# Facing issue while converting range of factor variables into numeric data type

Tags: r

I have list of factor variables.I tried converting those factor variables to numeric using below code

```
dat1[,c(27:47)] <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat1[,c(27:47)]))
```

Below is the error

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?""
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: have you tried as.character instead of as.factor?

Comment: Yes,i tried like as.character ,i get a warning message "NA'S introduced by coercion" and all my data turns into NA's.

Comment: can you add some sample data?  dput is useful for this